# Using LIKE in MySQL with a variable

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I would like to get a match for a query of the database using a LIKE operator in my SQL statement.

I'm looking at a field that has a date and time in it, like this

```
2012-04-27 12:00:00
```

I only want to compare the first part of the string, just the date bit, so I was using LIKE but I don't get any matches.

Here's the code

```
$colname_cruises = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$colname_cruises = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['id']);
}

$colname_date = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
$colname_date = $_GET['date'];
}

$query_cruises = sprintf("SELECT * FROM cruises WHERE title = %s AND departs LIKE %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_cruises, "text"), GetSQLValueString($colname_date, "text"));
$cruises = mysql_query($query_cruises, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises);
$totalRows_cruises = mysql_num_rows($cruises);
```

I'm pretty certain just doing a LIKE %s isn't enough... what else can I add in here ?

Comment: The % (what you need also for the LIKE)is getting replaced by the sprintf-function Parameters, right?

Comment: what is the datatype of your column where you save date and time

Comment: datatype is datetime, I've just modified the GetSQLValueString to date... still an empty query coming back

Comment: Try `LIKE %%%s%%` which will be translated to `%your_date%` by sprintf and will mean "your_date maybe prefixed by something and maybe followed by something". You may have to tweak a little depending on wether your GetSQLValueString function adds quotes ...

Comment: ok that returns this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'2012-04-27'%' at line 1

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Ugly, but should work, replace `GetSQLValueString($colname_date, "text")` with `"'%".substr(GetSQLValueString($colname_date, "text"), 1, -1)."%'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you  only want to compare the first part of the string, just the date  then why dont you use [**MySQL DATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) which

> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr

```
 SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
   -> '2003-12-31'
```

Comment: perfect, I used "SELECT * FROM cruises WHERE title = %s AND DATE(departs) LIKE %s" works a treat , thanks everyone / #diEcho

Answer (score 1):

For date comparison you can use between.
Try to use something like that:

```
departs between <date> and DATE_ADD(<date>,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 "SELECT * FROM cruises WHERE title = '".$colname_cruises."' AND departs LIKE '".$colname_date."%'";
```

If you want to fetch record where departs value starting string containg this date then you have to use `Like $str%`.

thanks